# Regex for a semi-colon separated list

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to use a regex to validate an entire string consisting of values separated by semi-colons.  For example, if each element is `[0-9]+`:

```
((^|;)[0-9]+)+$
```

This works in javascript, but not in ASP.Net [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sffh7429(v=vs.110).aspx) control.  I have seen solutions that involve duplicating the element:

```
^[0-9]+(;[0-9]+)*$
```

This is not suitable for me as the element regex I'm actually using is 280 characters long and needs to remain maintainable.

Is there some trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct. The first one, even when valid, will match strings with initial semicolons: `;1;2;3`, thus the alternation does not in fact do what you want.

There is no portable way to avoid the repetition if you only want to have a semicolon-*separated* string. If you need the regexp more maintainable than that, I suggest you use a function or external script to construct the regexp from string bits.

Unfortunately, I am not .NET expert, so I can't say if it has an extension that would allow for the non-repetition. Some other dialects, for instance [Oniguruma](http://rubular.com/r/bQVSvBfo5k), will allow you to do it nicely with group definitions:

```
(?<segment>[0-9]+)(;\g<segment>)+
```

Comment: I tried that out.  The validator matches the entire string, so frankly the '^' and '$' are redundant, just habit.  A leading `;` is being marked as invalid.

Comment: In JavaScript, where you stated that it works, the leading `;` is [not](http://regex101.com/r/yI9sU1/1) being marked as invalid.